# QSSLSocket flush crashes

Tags: flush, qtcpsocket, qsslsocket

```
qint64 sent = socket->write (data, size);
socket->flush ();
```

This works fine with a `QTcpSocket`, but eventually crashes within a memcpy inside a `QSSLSocket` private event (flush). I know I should add more context, but that's a lot. Omitting `socket->flush ()` here makes everything work perfectly incl. all SSL handshake etc, so I wonder if anybody has come across this? It takes a while and a few kilobytes or so of data sent before it happens. Maybe it's bad practice to flush after write anyway, so...just curious :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue and same as you was using flush after every write and sometimes "`Tag mismatch`" got in the way.
Solved problem:

`Remove flush usage after every write.`
And problem will be gone. `QSSLSockets` lib automatically flushes write buffer behind scenes, and it is more optimal than doing manual flush after each buffer data write :)